# Sync calendar entries on Samsung devices to Google Calendar

Tags: samsung, sync, google-calendar

The Calendar app on the Samsung Captivate is fed by the Google Calendar, but I have to make all my entries online. Otherwise, they are (uselessly) local to just my phone.

Is there any way to sync them back to my Google Calendar and (most importantly) include the events that I add from the calendar?

Comment: The default google calendar app work fine for me. If I enter an event to my phone calendar it will appear on the web calendar in less than a minute... maybe Samsung have fiddled with the handling of calendar events, on the Captivate. Some HTC owners also experience this problem too, btw.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "default" google calendar app.  I don't see such an app in the market, where do I get it?

Comment: I use the Calendar app from HTC, and I can enter events and have them appear on my google calendar. Are you sure you're adding your events to the right calendar? (you could be adding them to the local one instead of your google one)

Comment: There is a bug report logged with Google on the ability to set the default Calendar events are saved to, that would potentially sort this out http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3920

Comment: I'm running the Calendar 2.3.7 on top of Cyanogemod7 and it is not syncing back to the Calendar Web interface.

Comment: Related: [Sync local calendar entries with Google](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/85089/44325).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming Samsung have made the same changes for the Captivate as the Galaxy, then fully opening an appointment in the Calendar app and pressing Edit, you should have a line labelled "Calendar" that will say "My Calendar" (this is the local calendar on the phone), press the arrow beside that and it takes you to a list of your calendars and lets you select your Google Calendar to move the appointment there.

Also when you're in the Calendar and want to create a new appointment there are two ways to do it. Either long pressing on a day/time takes you to the quick appointment creation box, this always goes into your phone's local calendar and then needs moving out to your GCal. However if you press the Menu button and select "Create" then it takes you to the same screen as the Edit screen, and you can pick which calendar to save to from there.

Comment: long holding the date seems to force it into my calendar but just tapping, then yes, I see the other google cals and it seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use the Gemini calendar app, and it seems to sync back to your Google account.  It does, however, require the stock Google Calendar app, which based on your question, may pose a problem.