# Sync local calendar entries with Google

Tags: sync, google-calendar

I want to sync my calendar entries in my Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3) with Google. I am using the Google Calendar app but unfortunately I have entered everything into the default "My Calendar" local calendar rather than choosing my Google account when adding events.

I have not been able to find an easy way to transfer events from this calendar to my Google account, and hence it is not syncing (it seems you have to choose the right calendar to get it to sync).

Is there a way I can transfer my calendar entries to my Google account without manually re-entering everything?

Answer (score 1):

The procedure to do this has been outlined on [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2641118):

> 1. Firstly download this app from playstore: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts
> 2. Open it and go to Calendars Backup ➡Backup
> 3. Chose the file name and start the backup.
> 4. Then transfer the backup file to your pc. It will be in `/sdcard/SmsContactsBackup/calendars`.
> 5. Open up the backup file on your pc. I'd highly recommend you to use Notepad++ for this. You will see multiple Calendar entries at the
>      top of the file. Look for the entry which has this attribute:-
>      account_type="`LOCAL`" Note down the `_id attribute` for this Calendar
>      entry.
> 6. Now look for < Calendar entry which has name="xyz@gmail.com" attribute and note down the `_id attribute`. Here xyz is your gmail
>      username.
> 7. Now open Find & Replace and replace this :
>
> `calendar_id="1"`
>
> with
>
> `calendar_id="2"`
>
> *Here, 1 is the _id for LOCAL Calendar entry and 2 is the id for your Google Calendar (in this case). It could be different for you. So
>   basically whichever calendar entry is set as local, will be converted
>   to the google calendar's entry so that it can be synced.*
>
> 8. Now transfer the modified file back to `/sdcard/SmsContactsBackup/calendars`
> 9. Now open Superbackup  ➡Calendars and click on Delete all calendars.
> 10. Then restore the modified backup and re-sync your phone with the google calendar.
>
>     All your local entries will now appear as Google calendar entries and
>       will get synced properly to your account.

Answer (score 0):

The technique from XDA didn't work for me when migrating contacts from a local calendar on Android to a Google calendar, but the technique [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/32512324?hl=en&msgid=32534931) worked pretty well. The only problem I had with the suggestion was that importing using the phone didn't work, but taking the exported ICS file and importing it using the Google calendar website on a desktop machine worked flawlessly. The free version of this app allowed me to export just the calendar I wanted as an ICS file without issue. Here is the direction:

> you can migrate the events you've already entered on the Phone's calendar (to which you've been adding events with the Samsung Calendar App) into Google Calendar for free using a tool such as Calendar Sync Trial. Open the app and go to "Export" to create an ics (iCal) file containing the phone's calendar events, then import that file into a Google Calendar using a browser, or the same app. You can get Calendar Sync Trial from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icalparse.free

Answer (score 0):

I used the open source "Calendar Import-Export" app that let me export all calendars as `.ics` files. I copied them via USB to my computer and imported them in my Nextcloud calendar.

- https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.sufficientlysecure.ical/
- https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/calendar-import-export